# System of equations in two variables; solve it and separate the solutions by variable

Tags: equation-solving, homework

I have system of equations in two variables.

```
a x^2 + b y + c == 0
```

and

```
 x + y + 1 == 0
```

> 1. Please solve the system for `x` and `y` and name the result `list1`.
> 2. Separate list1 into two lists, `list2x` and `list2y`, where the elements of `list2x` are the solutions for `x` and the elements of `list2y`are the solutions for `y`.

**CLUE**

Answer of step 2 for x:

```
list2x = 
  {1/2 (-(b/a)-2 c+Sqrt[b^2-4 a c+4 a b c]/a),
   1/2 (-(b/a)-2 c-Sqrt[b^2-4 a c+4 a b c]/a)}
list2y = { ... }
```

This is not example for step2:

```
list2x=
  {{x -> -((-b + Sqrt[4 a b + b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a))},
   {x -> (b + Sqrt[4 a b + b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}}
```

Comment: Is it a hometask?

Comment: What have you tried and what problems are you running into? Do you have a Mathematica question? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but as it currently stands, it feels like you're outsourcing the solution of your problem.

Comment: Have you even looked up the basic tutorial for `Solve[]`?

Comment: I think the OP is after `ReplaceAll` (`/.`): `x /. {{x -> sol1}, {x -> sol2}}` gives `{sol1, sol2}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) to complete your homework assignment.

```
list1 = Solve[{a x^2 + b y + c == 0, x + y + 1 == 0}, {x, y}];
list2x = Cases[list1, (x -> s_) -> s, {2}]
list2y = Cases[list1, (y -> s_) -> s, {2}]

list2x
```

> `{-((-b + Sqrt[4 a b + b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)), 
>   (b + Sqrt[4 a b + b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}`

```
list2y
```

> `{1/2 (-2 - b/a + Sqrt[4 a b + b^2 - 4 a c]/a), 
>   1/2 (-2 - b/a - Sqrt[4 a b + b^2 - 4 a c]/a)}`

This is only one of many ways to do it.

Comment: Many Thanks . really good answer for me.